# Убрать Background в Alertgialog

Tags: android, android-studio

В `AlertDialog` Я хочу установить в качестве `background` векторный файл с прозрачным фоном. Я поместил этот векторный файл в качестве картинки в `xml` разметку для диалога. Все хорошо, но позади моей картинки есть белый фон, а не прозрачный.

Я удалял картинку из разметки, в самом `xml` прописывал прозрачный фон. Но белый фон оставался.

**Как убрать этот фон?**

Код тела в `DialogFragment`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.info_about_achienement, null, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String x=Integer.toString(args.getInt("num"));
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name_of_achi)).setText(x);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    builder.setView(v);
    return builder.create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропишите в `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">95%</item> //задать ширину (ландшафт)
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">95%</item> //задать ширину (портрет)
</style>
```

А в `DialogFragment`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
```

Comment: При этом размер вектора уменьшается. Как только указываю style в AlertDialog вектор не может в ширину принять нужное значение

Comment: видимо, он сжимается до "естественных" размеров. Попробуйте выставить ширину там же в стилях (обновил ответ) или прописать ее в `xml`

Comment: А как добавить SetCanceledOnTouchOutside в моем случае?

Comment: добавьте `Dialog dialog = builder.create();` до `return`, выставите ему нужные параметры и возвращайте `dialog`